# Would I use the subjunctive in this sentence?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

Would I use the subjunctive in this sentence?

> It will affect the economy in a manner that is bad.
>
> la afectará la economía de una manera que [es/sea] mala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative clause should be in the indicative, as it refers to a fact as expressed by the future "afectará":

- **Afectará** la economía de una manera que **es** mala.

Notice that, in a context of possibility rather than certainty, or with the negative, the subjunctive will be used:

- **Puede afectar** la economía de una manera que **sea** mala.
- **No afectará** la economía de una manera que **sea** mala.

Note 1: As you can see in my sentences above, I have eliminated "la". Since "la economía" is the direct object, using the pronoun "la" would generate a double direct object, and that is ungrammatical in Spanish.

Note 2: The relative clause "de una manera que es/sea mala" is really poor in the language. We would usually do away with the copulative verb and use a phrase like: "de un modo negativo".